# Undefined name '_LoginController' Flutter - Dart

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm new with flutter and Dart, I'm trying to use a method that's on my controller called LoginController, i already imported it but when i call the instance of my controller in a widget method theres an error that says Undefined name '_LoginController, need some help, pls!

Here my code:

The error message:

```
Undefined name '_LoginController'. (Documentation)  Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.
```

AndroidStudio suggestions are:
[image]

Import:
`import 'package:delivery_app/src/login/login_controller.dart';`

Instance on class _LoginPageState:

```
class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {

  LoginController _LoginController = new LoginController();

  @override
  void initState() {//Primer metodo que se ejecuta cuando inicial el App
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {//Inicializa controladores
      _LoginController.init(context);
    });
  }
```

Widget method where I'm calling my controller instance inside a onTap function:

```
Widget _rowElement(BuildContext context){
  return Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Text(
        'No tienes Cuenta?',
        style: TextStyle(
            color: MyColors.primaryColor
        ),
      ),
      const SizedBox(width: 7,),
      GestureDetector(
        onTap: _LoginController,//<---- THE ERROR IS HERE
        child: Text(
            'Registrate',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: MyColors.primaryColor
            )
        ),
      )
    ],
  );
}
```

My controller:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginController {

  BuildContext? context;

  Future? init(BuildContext context){
    this.context = context;
  }

  void registerPageRedi(BuildContext context){
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'register');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant define controller as the on tap method all you need to do is send the controller data to the function and perform the operation inside the function

Comment: Of course i can because im just trying to call a function that is inside de controller when i tap the button,  but the error im getting is weird...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: _LoginController.registerPageRedi(context),
  child: Text(
    'Registrate',
     style: TextStyle(
     fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
     color: MyColors.primaryColor
   )
  ),
),
```

Remove void from method

```
class LoginController {

  BuildContext? context;

  Future? init(BuildContext context){
    this.context = context;
  }

  registerPageRedi(BuildContext context){
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'register');
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved it, I moved the instance of LoginController out of the classes, now i can use it globally, although I think it's kinda weird because I was trying to access to the instance in the same class and the instance was still getting unrecognized

```dart
LoginController _loginController = new LoginController(); //Instance out of classes
    
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
    
}
    
class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {

}
```

Thanks to those who tried to help me :D